# Show "All" pages in DataTables along with responsive tables and other attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I dont know how to to merge the function of my current attibutes of responsive and fixed header etc with Show "All" list function like it has in this one https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

I dont know how to do it pls help here is my current function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    paging: false,
    columnDefs: [{
      searchable: false,
      orderable: false,
      targets: 0,
    }],
    order: [
      [1, 'asc']
    ],

  });
  new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);

  table.on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
    table.column(0, {
      search: 'applied',
      order: 'applied'
    }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
      cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
    });
  }).draw();
});
</script>
```

i am unable to merge the function with show "All" page length menu in javascript please help.
also please allow me run snippet im very new to js
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    paging: false,

    // Add this line
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    columnDefs: [{
      searchable: false,
      orderable: false,
      targets: 0,
    }],
    order: [
      [1, 'asc']
    ],

  });
  new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but this is not working... the table messes up the css and shows as non-paged